# JQGrid POST a column's value instead of ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to edit a record but instead of sending the value of the ID column, it keeps sending the ID for the table, which I do not care about. Here's the code:

```
$("#list1").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'clientSide',             
                colNames: ["Id", "Id prodotto", "Nome prodotto", "Quantità",
                           "Pista", "Politica", "Attivazione", "Bundle",
                           "Scontato", "Valore sconto", "Twin card", "DN",
                           "ISDN", "Disabilitato"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "id", hidden:true, key:true},
                    { name: "idprodotto", hidden:true},             
                    { name: "prodotto"},
                    { name: "quantita"},
                    { name: "pista"},
                    { name: "politica"},
                    { name: "attivazione", formatter: "checkbox"},
                    { name: "bundle", formatter: "checkbox"},
                    { name: "sconti", formatter: "checkbox"},
                    { name: "scontival"},
                    { name: "card", formatter: "checkbox"},
                    { name: "numero"},
                    { name: "isdn", formatter: "checkbox"},
                    { name: "disabilitato", width:100, sortable: false, resizable:false, hidden:true }
                ],  
            sortname: "prodotto",
            sortorder: "asc",
            pager: "#pager1"
            })          
            .navGrid('#pager1', {add: false, del: false});
```

It may help to say that in this page there are two tables, here's the first one:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'clientSide',
                colNames: [
                           "Id",
// "Id cliente",
                         "Numero",  "RagSociale cliente", "Anno",
                           "Data di ordine", "Id agente", "Nome agente", "Cognome agente",
                           "Id agenzia", "RagSociale agenzia", "Id utente", "Nome utente", 
                           "Data d'inserimento", "Note", "Disabilitato",""],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "id", hidden:true, key:true },
//                      { name: "idCliente"},   
                    { name: "numero"},  
                    { name: "ragSocCliente"},
                    { name: "anno"},
                    { name: "dataOrdine"},              
                    { name: "idAgente"},
                    { name: "nomeAgente"},
                    { name: "cognomeAgente"},
                    { name: "idAgenzia"},
                    { name: "ragSocAgenzia"},
                    { name: "idUser"},
                    { name: "nomeUser"},                                            
                    { name: "dataInserimento"},             
                    { name: "note"},                
                    { name: "disabilitato", width:100, sortable: false, resizable:false, hidden: true},
                    { name: "dataModifica", width:100, hidden: false}
                ],

                sortname: "dataModifica",
                sortorder: "desc",
                pager: "#pager",
                onSelectRow: function (id) {                    
                    sessionStorage.setItem("idEdit", $("#list").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'id'));
                    $.get("getCorpoByNumero.do", {                          
                        id: sessionStorage.getItem("idEdit")
                    },  function (data) {
                            $("#list1").clearGridData();
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                     
                                var corpo = data[i];                                                
                                $("#list1").addRowData((i+1), corpo);

                            }
                    });

                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear *which "column's value"* you want to POST instead of ID? Which grid have the problem? You use `navGrid` for the grid `#list1` **without** specifying and `editurl` which looks incorrect.

The filling of the second grid using `addRowData` is very bad! Especially bad would be to use values `0`, ..`data.length` as the rowids instead of ids returned from the server (from `"getCorpoByNumero.do"`). It's much more effective to change `data` parameter of the grid and to reload it by `.trigger("reloadGrid")`:

```js
onSelectRow: function (id) {                    
    sessionStorage.setItem("idEdit", id);
    $.get("getCorpoByNumero.do", {                          
        id: id
    }, function (data) {
        var $grid1 = $("#list1"), p = $grid1.jqGrid("getGridParam");

        p.data = data;
        $grid1.trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
}
```

Moreover the usage of `idPrefix` is strictly recommended if you create more as one grid on the page. The standard behavior of jqGrid is setting `id` attribute of all `<tr>` elements of the grid (setting the rowid) to the value of `id` property of input data. It can produce id dupplicates if both grids would have the same `id` value. The usage of `idPrefix: "g1_"` for example in the `#list1` grid will force adding `"g1_"` prefix to all `id` values of the grid. It fixes possible id duplicates. The prefix will be automatically stripped during sending the data to the server.

The last remark. I'd recommend you to remove unneeded `{ name: "id", hidden:true, key:true }` column from the grids. The rowid will use `id` property of input data automatically. Instead of `$("#list").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'id')` you can use just `id` in the `onSelectRow` callback and to have the same data. In the same way you can remove other hidden columns (`disabilitato` and `idprodotto`). The internal data will still have *all input properties* and you can use `getLocalRow` to access the data.

I recommend to replace `datatype: 'clientSide'` to more common `datatype: 'local'` and verify which version of jqGrid you use. I recommend you to use the latest version (4.13.1) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the for of jqGrid, which I develop.

Comment: The problem is in the First table (List1), when I press edit, it send a request for the wrong ID, instead of the ID of the row, I want to send the value in the "id" column

Comment: @Malignus: The problem exist because you fill the grid in the wrong way: using `addRowData`. Do you tried the modification which I suggest?

Comment: I kept the session storage as it was, because I use it to get the ID of the column id of the table ("#list"). The rest is as you wrote it and it still doesn't work

Comment: @Malignus: What is not work? Could you prepare clear demo (in fsfiddle, for example) with some test data?